# Comparing two tables in Java (not database)

Tags: java, collections

I have to compare 2 similar tables in Java, probably using collection class. But the input source is clipboard not database. Sample tables:-

```
Table1:
 |EmpID| Name| Age|Dept|
 |123|John|30|Ops|
 |456|Peter|40|HR|

Table2:
|EmpID| Name| Age|Dept|
|123|John|30|Ops|
|462|Peter|40|Dev|
```

Here Emp ID is unique. Row1 of Table1 should compare to Row1 of Table2 & so on. If EmpID & data in corresponding columns match it should display as match.
If EmpID do not match as in 2nd row it should report as  Diff, Search in next row of Table2 & find the EmpID. Report if match.
If not found should report as extra in Table1 or Miss in Table2. All These rows have to be reported after comparison as Match, Diff,Extra or Miss.

Have tried to use nested HashMap here for comparison purpose which works fine when only one row is to be compared.
When multiple rows are added to the HashMap, it does a Cartesian product comparison I.e. Table1, Row 1 with Table2 ,Row2 & so on hence getting wrong input. (Please see a sample code below). 
Could you please suggest how I could do these comparisons/iterations as I also have to do reporting after the comparison.

```
HashMap<String,String> Table1= new HashMap<String,String>();
Table1. put( Name, "John");
Table1. put(Age,"30");  
Table1.put(Dept, "Ops"); 

HashMap<String,String> Table2= new   HashMap<String,String>();
Table2.put( Name, "John");
Table2. put(Age,"30"); 
Table2.put(Dept, "Ops"); 

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>Table3= new    HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
Table3.put(EmpId, "123"); 

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>Table4= new   HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
Table4.put(EmpId, "123"); 

List<String> match = new List<String>();
List< String> diff = new List<String>();

for ( String tempe: Table3.keySet()){ 
for(String temp: Table4.keySet()) {

If(tempe.equals temp){
System.out.println("Emp Id match");

for(String tem: Table1.keySet()){
for(String te: Table2.keySet()){

If(tem equals te){
match.add( tem);
}else{
diff.add(temp + te);
} 
}
}
else{
System.out.println(" EmpId not matching");
}
}
}

for( String mat: match){
 System.out println("Matched values: + mat ");
 }
for( String dif: diff){
System.out.println("Different values: + dif");
}
```

The desired output is:

Match:
Emp ID : 123 
Key:  Name, Age, Dept
Values: John, 30, Ops

Diff:
Emp ID: 456
Key: Dept
Values: HR, Dev

Extra :
InTable1 : Emp ID: 789 (print key & values, if any) 
In Table2:  EmpId : 879 (print key & values of any)

Miss:
 In Table1: 
Emp ID: 489
Name, Age, Dept
Xyz, 26, Ops
In Table2: similarly if any

Comment: can you post the desired output from your example ? Requirement is not very clear to me

Comment: You should use classes/objects to hold your data appropriately, when you find yourself nesting maps/collections it's almost always time to rethink design (as you can see, this gets very convoluted and messy to work with fast). Then comparisons would be about one line of code

Answer (score 1):

Shardha Lets make a better design approach.

Here I have preapred 2 tables as 2 hashMaps.  key of each hashmap is empid and value is a "EmpDetails" object. This empdetails will hold age,name,department as attributes.we can set these values using a constructor. Here i have also overridden "equals" method to compare 2 objects.

I havent understood your requirement for "Miss" and "Extra" properly. But I think its a small segment and u can add it by ur own. Please find below the main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,EmpDetails> table1=new HashMap<String,EmpDetails>();
    Map<String,EmpDetails> table2=new HashMap<String,EmpDetails>();

    EmpDetails emp1=new EmpDetails("John", "30", "Ops");
    table1.put("123",emp1);

    EmpDetails emp2=new EmpDetails("John", "30", "Ops");
    table2.put("123",emp2);

    EmpDetails emp3=new EmpDetails("Amy", "30", "Ops");
    table1.put("127",emp3);

    EmpDetails emp4=new EmpDetails("Rachel", "30", "Ops");
    table2.put("127",emp4);

    List<String> match = new ArrayList<String>();
    List< String> diff = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String empIdTable1:table1.keySet())
    {
        EmpDetails tempemp1;
        EmpDetails tempemp2;
        for(String empIdTable2:table2.keySet())
        {
            if(empIdTable1.equalsIgnoreCase(empIdTable2))
            {
                tempemp1=table1.get(empIdTable1);
                tempemp2=table2.get(empIdTable2);
                if(tempemp1.equals(tempemp2))
                {
                    match.add(empIdTable1);
                    break;
                }else{
                    diff.add(empIdTable1);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(" Match :"+match);
    System.out.println(" diffn :"+diff);

}

 }
```

Here is the Empdeatils class :

```
 public class EmpDetails {
    private String name;
  private String age;
   private String dept;
   public EmpDetails(String name, String age, String dept) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.dept = dept;
   }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Boolean response=false;
    if(obj!=null && obj instanceof EmpDetails)
    {
        EmpDetails objParam=(EmpDetails)obj;

        if(objParam.name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name) && objParam.age.equalsIgnoreCase(this.age) && objParam.dept.equalsIgnoreCase(this.dept))
        {
            response=true;
        }
    }
    return response;
  }


    }
```

Please mention your further queries in comments to this answer.